# How to import a file which referenced in module

Tags: python-2.7

I created a module and it contains the file's name. But when I use the module instead of the file's name, the 'from' code doesn't work.

```
svn = raw_input("What file are you looking for?")
from svn import *
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer, it should be like this:

```
svn = raw_input("What file are you looking for?")
__import__(svn)
```